# How do I catch this fancy exception: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) relation "table" already exists

Tags: python, exception

I've decided to stop with the

```
Try:
  function()
except:
  generic handler()
```

So how do I catch a fancy error like this?  It's not:

```
Try:
  function()
except sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) as err:
  generic handler()
```

Also, these exceptions are really difficult to use.  Like if I want to close the connection and then raise, how do I know what to raise without looking into the source code.

Comment: Do you want to re-raise the exception you just caught? Simply call `raise` with no arguments in the end of `except` block.

Comment: Usually exceptions will be documented as part of the module, and you can import them just like any other symbol.  If you had some runnable code instead of `function()` and `generic handler()` it would be easy to give you an example!  If you just want to close and raise, you might want `finally` instead of `except`.

Comment: See the docs on sqlalchemy's exceptions here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/exceptions.html

Comment: This is very important. So its a sqlalchemy exception, not a psycopg2 exception.  I'd go import sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError and except sqlalchemy.esc.ProgrammingError as err:?  The reason why it's throwing it is I'm writing to the database and there's some relation doesn't exist.  I want. to catch it and make the relation if it happens.